# RegEx for matching HTML tags with specific attributes

Tags: javascript, html, regex, dom, regex-group

I have a string like

```
<span title="use a <label>">Some Content</span>
<span title="use a <div>">Some Other Content</span>
```

I need a regex to get only the `Some Content` or `Some Other Content` ignoring the tags, even if the tags has another tags inside

Comment: If you're in JS, [parse it as a document fragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) and use the DOM.  Regex is the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: Agree with @Amy. Are you scraping the page or JS in the page?

Comment: Is the invalid html intentional? I.e having a closing label tag on a span opening tag.

Comment: Regex is [absolutely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4665) the wrong tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [document parser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) and DOM methods to get the content, not regular expressions.  Regex is decidedly the wrong tool for this job. Even if you can get a regex that works, it will be difficult to understand and very brittle.  The solution that follows is much more robust, easier to understand, and easier to debug.

Start by creating a parser and parsing the document fragment:

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(
    '<span title="use a <label>">Some Content</label><span title="use a <div>">Some Other Content</label>',
    "text/html");
```

You can see the result by inspecting `doc.documentElement`, which gives us:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <span title="use a <label>">
            Some Content
            <span title="use a <div>">
                Some Other Content
            </span>
        </span>
    </body>
</html>
```

Because your tags aren't closed properly, it parses it weird, but it doesn't matter.  The text content is still content.

Next, we use a [document walker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker) to extract all of the text nodes.  You can create a new walker using [createTreeWalker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTreeWalker), passing in [`NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeFilter):

```
var walker = doc.createTreeWalker(
    doc.documentElement,    // root
    NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,   // what to show
    null,                   // filter
    false);                 // reference expansion
```

We can then walk the tree and collect all of the walked nodes:

```
var node;
var textNodes = []; 
while (node = walker.nextNode()) {
    textNodes.push(node);
}
```

Finally, we get the desired array:

```
var content = textNodes.map(x => x.textContent);
```

Content is an array containing `["Some Content", "Some Other Content"]`, the desired result set.

Answer (score 2):

We might just use a simple expression and collect our desired textContents, maybe using:

```
">(.+?)<\/
```

Our data is saved in `(.+?)` capturing group.

```js
const regex = /">(.+?)<\//gm;
const str = `<span title="use a <label>">Some Content</label>
<span title="use a <div>">Some Other Content</label>`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/WkaJZy/1/)

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired, it can be modified or changed in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/WkaJZy/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

May be you get some idea.

Regex:     ">(.*)</

```
Match 1
Full match  26-42   ">Some Content</
Group 1.    n/a Some Content
Match 2
Full match  73-95   ">Some Other Content</
Group 1.    n/a Some Other Content
```

https://regex101.com/r/6VArPY/1